# ionic 4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

Tags: angular, oop, ionic-framework

Being the good programmer that I *try* to be I installed a linter and husky. When I was going through the linters, I arrived at the `app.component.ts` file and everything was red. It didn't like how there were declarations within the constructor. Alright, no problem, I changed:

```
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    }
```

to

```
  private platform: Platform;
  private splashScreen: SplashScreen;
  private statusBar: StatusBar;

  public constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    ){
     this.initializeApp();
     this.platform = platform;
     this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
     this.statusBar = statusBar;
    }
```

however, following the change I got all types of errors:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

this is referring to:

```
  public initializeApp(): void {
    this.platform.ready().then( // <----ERROR
      (): void => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      },
    );
  }
```

and then I would also get an error about Type and assigning to `any[]`

the main question I have is why? Why is constructor declaration of a private instance OK, but then declaring it privately outside the constructor, still passing it through the constructor `this.platform` is not being found. Also, how can I get the same results without my linter complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private platform: Platform;
  private splashScreen: SplashScreen;
  private statusBar: StatusBar;

  public constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    ){
     this.initializeApp(); // <-- initialize app called here.
     this.platform = platform; // <-- platform assigned here.
     this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
     this.statusBar = statusBar;
    }
```

Because `initializeApp` is invoked **BEFORE** assigning `this.platform`, its original value is `undefined`.
Just move the initializeApp **after** the assignments:

```
     this.platform = platform; // <-- platform assigned here.
     this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
     this.statusBar = statusBar;
     this.initializeApp(); // <-- initialize app called here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `this.platform = platform;` before `this.initializeApp();`, if not your private properties will be undefined. Your linter should be ok with the following code:

```
public constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    ){
     this.platform = platform;
     this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
     this.statusBar = statusBar;
     this.initializeApp();
    }
```

Comment: It's amazing how quickly you get frustrated and look over basic stuff sometimes! ahhhg